# Rails dummy object added to Active Record Array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I use rails 4.2 and I found a weird issue:

```
 @tweet = current_user.tweets.new
 @tweets = current_user.tweets
```

When I loop over in Views like:

```
<%= render @tweets %>
```

I get an Extra Record with null id.

Example:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: There's not enough info here to know why this extra record is showing up. How about showing the code where you define these instance variables? By the way, it's the convention on StackOverflow to paste code as text instead of screenshot (unless it's really necessary).

Comment: I guess your `tweets/form` build a new Tweet (perhaps like `form_for Tweet.new`), is that possible?

Comment: The same bug appears , even if I write the code for Tweet.new in partial and render .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You build this empty `Tweet` yourself in your controller:

```
@tweet = current_user.tweets.new
@tweets = current_user.tweets
```

There are several ways to avoid this problem. You could build the new Tweet without adding it to the `@tweets` array:

```
@tweet = Tweet.new(user: current_user)
@tweets = current_user.tweets
```

Or you could change your your to exclude `tweets` that haven't been saved to the database yet:

```
<%= render @tweets.select(&:persistent?) %>
```

Comment: That Worked, It would be helpful for me if you can explain why did it behave like this.

It should not add Non Persistent Record to @tweets as per my understanding.

Comment: `current_user.tweets` returns an array with all the user's `tweets`. `current_user.tweets.new` adds a new tweet to that array. This is how it works. Not sure how to explain. Why do you think it should not add that record to the array?

Comment: I think it should not add as I have two instance variables tweet which holds new object for Tweet and other tweets which query DB and store only persisted Objects.

Comment: Both us use the same `current_user.tweets` in both cases. I would be very surprised if I call `current_user.tweets` twice and get different results in both cases.